# Can you automatically open a downloaded document on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html

all,

We have a HTML5 page and let's say there are image links on it. Can we have Android to automatically open up that image if user tap on it? Of course first it will download it, then open it. 
I am wondering if it is possible? If it is possible, there are several concerns about it too:
1. How does the Android know which app can open it?
2. That can bring up a security issue too. What if the link is a bad link or linked to some virus code? 
What do you guys think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automatically open such a link in a different application without first writing your own application to do so. If you are running your own application and not using the default Browser (or Chrome or Opera or Dolphin or whatever other app), then you can manually fire off a new `Intent` when the links are clicked.

However, this doesn't necessarily need to be an android-specific question. In order to view an image, a web browser needs to download it regardless. What is to stop you from opening up a full-screen `<div>` with the image and associated metadata within it? If you're wanting to open it in a specific app, you're out of luck unless the app authors provided you with a specific way to do it.

You pointed out the exact reason that this is not directly possible. Certain applications are able to directly open content from the web (maybe, it's been a long time since I tried and I wasn't using the stock browser at the time) because such content is written using a URI scheme that Android can parse. There is no such (standard) URI scheme for images outside of simple HTTP/FTP, and both of those will be loaded in the browser app.

tl;dr: you can't do this from JS or HTML directly, but can write your own app to accomplish it if it is absolutely critical or display the image in a full-screen `<div>` in your html page.